# Web rendering using Composite design pattern

Tags: design-patterns, web, web-frameworks

Can anyone direct me to a web framework / library that uses the Composite design pattern for rendering in the following manner: render() is called on the root object (which possibly delegates to a html rendering strategy); recursion through its descendants' render methods subsequently generates the page's html?

Comment: *Rendering* is confusing in your question. Sounds like you want an HTML generator that supports Composite à la Gang of Four structures? You use the term "html rendering strategy", which is basically what a web browser does, and I think you meant HTML generating strategy, right?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator yeah, generation. Sorry for the confusion.